# How Windows locate Chrome

Tags: c#, powershell, google-chrome

I am trying to understand what happens when I run `start chrome` in Powershell.

I built [PowerShell](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell) from [this commit](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/commit/f4ac0935c530be5b33c3fc043b574b95d41a1ca5) (modify [global](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/global.json) to ur dotnet version), traced `start chrome` till plain `Process.Start` [call](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/f4ac0935c530be5b33c3fc043b574b95d41a1ca5/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Management/commands/management/Process.cs#L2581) (`Start-Process` is documented about this behaviour, but still I double-checked). Then I've traced in runtime till [kernel call](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/832a65623d180412fcbaefd68aa57065341db931/src/libraries/System.Diagnostics.Process/src/System/Diagnostics/Process.Win32.cs#L51), filename still not resolved.

Nor my `PATH`, nor any of my `ENVIRONMENTAL_VARIABLES` does not have anything about chrome. I run [this article](https://4sysops.com/archives/find-the-product-guid-of-installed-software-with-powershell/) to find out, that there is `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Google Chrome` registry entry, and yeap, it does contain the path to chrome, but how does the kernel understand, that exactly
`chrome` Process.FileName is `Google Chrome` application in the registry? I can omit extension in `dotnet` because it's in the `PATH`, but why does `start chrome` even work?

I don't understand how do Windows locate google chrome.
Please help, I am very curious.

Comment: As a side note, there are many ways to activate your default browser from powershell.  For example, Start-process followed by a URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are stored in the registry under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths`.

Check the article on [Application Registration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/app-registration).